# about read system call in c

Tags: c, linux

when i use read system call, the buffer that i provide in the second argument, where the data
from reading are supposed to get stored, gets overwritten right!?

thanks,
Nikos

Comment: Yes, the values in the buffer are overwritten.

Comment: What OS? Are you talking about the system call or the fread function from stdio? If I am to guess at what you are asking, then yes the buffer is overwritten.

Comment: i was talking about the linux kernel system call, thanx for the answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the point of `read()`, to fill (=overwrite) the buffer with the content read from the file.

Comment: i was talking about the linux kernel system call, thanx for the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Only as many bytes as the value returned from the [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) call are overwritten.

```
ovr = read(f, buf, 1000);
if (ovr < 0) /* error */;
/* `ovr` bytes of `buf` were overwritten */
```